# Calculating some equations

Tags: java, function, equations

Having these functions:

```
f(x)= 4(x-1)(x-3)/(0-1)(0-3)
g(x)= 2(x-0)(x-3)/(1-0)(1-3)
h(x)= 3(x-0)(x-1)/(3-0)(3-1)
```

I want to calculate their sum `mod p`. For reference, `p=7`.

However, what interests me mostly is the coefficients of the powers of x from the final result. Will show you what I mean

My steps:

```
f(x)=4(x-1)(x-3)/3
g(x)=-(x-0)(x-3)
h(x)=(x-0)(x-1)/2

f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=(8(x-1)(x-3)-6(x-0)(x-3)+3(x-0)(x-1))/6
=(8(x^2-4x+3)-6(x^2-3x)+3(x^2-x))/6
=(8x^2-32x+24-6x^2+18x+3x^2-3x)/6
=(5x^2-17x+24)/6

1/6 mod 7=6
```

So, we get to multiply by 6 instead of dividing the parenthesis, which will be made mod 7, too:

```
=(5x^2-17x+24)*6
=30x^2-102+144
```

This will also be mod 7, but if I can get the coefficients I can do it separately for each of them. The final result will be `2x^2+3x+4`

So, what interests me are the coefficients 30, -102 and 144(or 2,3,4, doesn't matter). How can I compute in java to get them from f+g+h, if there is a faster or easier way(I may have done useless steps in my calculations)?

Comment: Are you performing the divisions mod 7?

Comment: Do you have a generalization of the problem in mind? Because now that you've already done the computation, the solution in Java is just some form of `return new int[] {2, 3, 4};`.

Comment: Yes. Dividing by 6 means multiplying by 6^(-1) which mod 7 means multiplying by 6. Because 6^(-1) mod 7 is 6.

Comment: @user2357112 Well in the initial phase I have f+g+h, NOT 2x^2+3x+4. That would be too simple :D

Comment: Yes, but now that you've computed `f+g+h`, you can just `return new int[] {2, 3, 4};`. Do you have some more general input form you're supposed to handle?

Comment: My question is how to compute f+g+h. I didn't compute them, that is my question. How to compute them to get the coefficients 2,3,4?

Comment: Probably you are looking for BigInteger's modInverse (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse(java.math.BigInteger))?

Comment: What interests me more is how to break the parenthesis in a program. I already am aware of modInverse. Just don't know how to compute equations.

Comment: "How to compute them to get the coefficients 2,3,4?" - *you just did*. You expanded them using the normal rules for polynomial multiplication, added like terms, multiplied by appropriate multiplicative inverses, and reduced mod 7. That's pretty much the same thing you'd do with a computer program.

Comment: "how to break the parenthesis" - is this about input parsing, or polynomial algebra with modular coefficients?

Comment: But I don't know how to compute polynomial multiplication. That's what I'm trying to ask specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are computing [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

In the specific case of 3 data points (x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) - which in your example are (0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 3), the calculation is quite easy.

f(x) = y_0*l_0(x) = y_0/((x_0-x_1)*(x_0-x_2))*(x^2 + -(x_1+x_2)*x + (x_1*x_2))

The other two polynomials can be computed similarly.

In their sum, you just have to group together the corresponding coefficients, and make the modular arithmetic.
(Division can be made with the multiplication of the inverse element, and the inverse element can be easily computed with the help of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) as a^(p-2) in case of prime modulus.)